# Can we rename a resource collection/member URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this resource in routes.rb

```
resources :orders, only:[] do
    collection do 
      post :user_order_confirmation
    end  
 end
```

which creates a path like this in HTML views 'orders/carrier_order_confirmation'. Can we do something that this path looks like this 'orders/user_confirmation'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
resources :orders, only:[] do
    collection do 
      post :user_confirmation, acion: :user_order_confirmation
    end  
 end
```

This will give you the exact route as you are looking for. Here is the test :

```
$ rake routes | grep orders
user_confirmation_orders POST /orders/user_confirmation(.:format) orders#user_confirmation {:acion=>:user_order_confirmation}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the conventional routes by adding the following line in your routes.rb after you set the resource routes:

```
get "/orders/user_confirmation" => "orders#user_confirmation", as: "user_confirmation"
```

To clarify, here's what each part of that means:

```
[Routing Method] "/[Route You want]" => "[Controller]#[Controller Method]", as: "[Custom Route Name]"
```

Comment: I guessed at what you were naming the controller/ method, but if you follow the general pattern you can use this to name any custom route

Comment: I understand that but I want to do this same thing using resources syntax. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think so with the nesting setup you have, I think Rails would always default it to the convention

Answer (score 0):

Try this
post :user_order_confirmation, as: :user_confirmation

Comment: With this Rails as changed the helper name to "user_confirmation_orders " but not path in html views.